# jdk jdbc bit issue

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, java

I am trying to get the mapviewer running. Whatever I do I get either one of these error messages:

```
Data source cannot be created : C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
\bin\ocijdbc10.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

---

```
Data source cannot be created : C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
\bin\ocijdbc10.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I understand that it has to do with the jdk/dll bit version. However, as I have tried all possibilities can someone please suggest a solution which I may have overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the Thin driver?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not use java for a long time so I am not sure what you mean. I just want to get something running. These are my options: JDBC URL, J2EE DS, TNS name

Comment: Please google the diffrence between Thin and OCI driver.

Comment: You first need to try thin client JDBC driver and if it works OK and you are looking for performance issues then consider the Instant Client.

Comment: Ok I understand but I do not think I can use the 'thin access' in my situation (see options above) unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the OCI driver.  Try using the thin JDBC driver instead.  This is platform agnostic.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

The OCI driver works with the installed Oracle client and therefore requires native DLLs.  The thin driver is pure Java.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure whether I have the option. These are my 3 options: JDBC URL, J2EE DS, TNS name

Comment: As the FAQ explains that Dan posted a link to, make sure that your JDBC URL starts with `jdbc:oracle:thin:` and not `jdbc:oracle:oci:`.

Comment: Not sure whether I can change this in my situation. I am trying to get this running: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10464_05/web.904/b10559/vis_star.htm on my local machine.

Comment: Ok - so looking at this it seems that you can't use the thin drivers with this product as it doesn't allow you to specify the URL.  So this looks more like a platform issue - are you using 64 bit Windows but this is a 32 bit application that requires 32 bit linking in the OS?

Comment: I seem to be able to use thin when I go the manual way via XML: http://www.dbuggr.com/smallwei/step-step-instruction-install-oracle-mapviewer-10g-10-1-3-1/ Ill give this a go ...